# How to specify play-services-location

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I would like to use googlePlayServicesVersion 16.1.0, but than I get

> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.1.0

I have tried adding `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'` inside app/build.gradle dependencies

I have added `googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0"` inside android/build.gradle

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25293#issuecomment-503008149

Answer (score 5):

The version `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.1.0` [**doesn't exist**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).

You can use one of these:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0
```

You can also check the in [maven google repo](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html):

[image]

Comment: In your `module/build.gradle` file use `dependencies { implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0' }`

Comment: Sorry but my question was bad, I have just found that some external library was using googlePlayServicesVersion for play-services-location